# Show options in the table header over the table body

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a table. In the `<th>` of the `<header>` there is a `<select>` with options and size = 1:

```
<select multiple size="1"  class="filtersForCombobox" style="width:90%" name="filter2_status_id">
            <option value="">Select</option>
            {foreach from=$aDropDownsForFilters.status item=sName key=iIdCombobox}
                <option value="{$iIdCombobox}" {if $oBlock->compareStatuses($iIdCombobox) || in_array($iIdCombobox, $aFiltersData.status_id)} selected="selected"{/if}>{$sName|tr}</option>
            {/foreach}
 </select>
```

I need to show all select options on mouseover. For this I use jquery:

```
$(document).on('mouseover','.filtersForCombobox',function () {
     $(this).attr("size",$(this).find("option").length);
});
```

But the problem is that I expand the header and it looks bad.

How can I show the options in the table header over the table body?

Thanks.

Comment: Anybody can help?

Answer (score 0):

You can use absolute positioning. I added an `&nbsp;` to the `th` so it will calculate a normal height. I also added an event handler for when the mouseleaves that sets the size attribute back to 1.

```js
$( document ).on( 'mouseenter', '.cars', function() {
  $(this).attr("size", $(this).find("option").length);
  $(this).focus();
}).on( 'mouseleave', '.cars', function() {
  $(this).attr("size", 1);
});
```

```css
th {
 position: relative;
}
.cars {
  width: 90%;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 5%;
}

.cars option:hover {
  background: rgb( 30, 144, 255);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table>
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th>
        &nbsp;
        <select multiple id="mySelect" size="1" class="cars">
          <option value="volvo">Volvo</option>
          <option value="saab">Saab</option>
          <option value="opel">Opel</option>
          <option value="audi">Audi</option>
        </select>
      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <p> asdf as fd sda fdsa fds af sdaf dsa fds afd saf a fsa dfsa fdsa fd safd saf dsa</p>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks. But why option background doesn't change when hover?

Comment: I think there are two things you are seeing. First of all, a select with size="1" requires you to give the element the focus, generally by clicking it, so that it knows to open the dropdown with the options. Secondly, when a select has a size that is more than 1, it appears that the hover effects are disabled. I suspect that is a choice rather than dealing with the cases where the size isn't equal to the number of options and the UX gets tricky. I added js to focus the input on hover and some css to try add the bg color on hover feature. Not cross-browser tested.